# Error starting method from action bar button

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I am trying to create a button on the action bar that will activate a method that is in the same activity.

Below is my menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".AddContactActivityOCR">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/undo"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="UNDO"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Below are my relevant codes in the activity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_contact_undo, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.undo:
                onRewrite();
                return true;

            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

 public void onRewrite(View v){
        listName.setText(recognizedText);
        listOwner.setText(recognizedText);
        companyName.setText(recognizedText);
        companyAddress.setText(recognizedText);
        companyNumber.setText(recognizedText);

        mCurrentLang = mFromLang;

        validator(recognizedText);
    }
```

I am trying to start "onRewrite()" when I click the "UNDO" button on my action bar.

However it shows the error below:
[image]

I tried using "android:onClick="onRewrite" on a normal button and it is able to start this method. Why is it not starting "onRewrite" in this case?

Comment: Let me know your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***why its show error?***

you have create method with parameter View like `onRewrite(View v)` and you are trying to call it without parameter that's why its show you that message.

remove parameter from method. like below

```
public void onRewrite(){ .... // your code}
```

---

> I tried using "android:onClick="onRewrite" on a normal button and it
>   is able to start this method.

[why its working?](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick)

---

want to use method to work in both case. create two method with same name & use same code inside that.

```
public void onRewrite(){ .... // your code}
public void onRewrite(View v){ .... // your code}
```

---

another solution is create button click in activity and remove `android:onClick="onRewrite` from layout.xml, call `onRewrite()` from click event as well as from `onOptionsItemSelected`

Answer (score 2):

Change your  Activity code

Error Because you calling method On onRewrite() without Parameter

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_contact_undo, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.undo:

                onRewrite();

                return true;

            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

 public void onRewrite(){
        listName.setText(recognizedText);

        listOwner.setText(recognizedText);

        companyName.setText(recognizedText);

        companyAddress.setText(recognizedText);

        companyNumber.setText(recognizedText);

        mCurrentLang = mFromLang;

        validator(recognizedText);
    }
```

Hope this will helps you